# read a list from a file and sort them using xcode NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

i am trying to read from a plist file more than 10000 recored but whenever i run it crashes here is the code i am using the problem it can not read from plist

```
-(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender{

 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"news" ofType:@"plist"];
 NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

then i using sort program  .....

but the above is not working here is also he plist file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <string>4</string>
    <string>2</string>
    <string>5</string>
    <string>8</string>
    <string>1</string>
</array>
</plist>
```

@implementation sort_algViewController

```
-(IBAction)clicked:(id)sender{

 //id temp;
 NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:
 @"news" ofType:@"plist"];

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    NSLog(@"%@",path);
        printf("YeS");
    }
 //NSMutableArray *array = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"9", @"7",@"3", @"5", nil]mutableCopy];
 //myarray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: @"bdata.txt" ];
 NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: path];

//  NSString *array = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile: path];
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
//  NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    NSLog(@"%@",array);
    NSLog(@"%@",path);
 //printf("before Array x: ");

 //bubbleSort(array);   // sort the array
 int n = [array count]  ;
 for (int i = 0; i < n-1; i++)
 for (int j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
 if ([[array objectAtIndex: j] compare:
 [array objectAtIndex: j+1]] == NSOrderedDescending)

//#define SWAP(arr, x, y) 
     do {   
         id oldX = [array objectAtIndex: (j)];  
         [array replaceObjectAtIndex: (j) withObject: [array objectAtIndex: (j+1)]];
         [array replaceObjectAtIndex: (j+1) withObject: oldX];  
     } while (0);


     printf("array");
     NSString *element;
        NSEnumerator *iterator = [array objectEnumerator];
        while ((element = [iterator nextObject]) != nil)
            printf("%s ", [element UTF8String]); 
        printf("\n");

[array release];    // array needs to be released! 

 [pool release];

//return EXIT_SUCCESS;


 }
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Check that:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"news" ofType:@"plist"];
```

does not return a nil value for `path`. (You can add an NSLog trace for that).

If this does not fix the problem, please attach the output on the console and the exact line where it crashes.

EDIT:

Replace the statement:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: path];
```

with:

```
NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: path] retain];
```

*or* remove the line:

```
[array release];    // array needs to be released!
```

and you should be fine.

The way your code is currently written, you are releasing an autoreleasead array, which is not correct. Thus, either you add a retain, or you remove the release.

Comment: 2012-04-09 21:41:18.803 sort_alg[668:207] /Users/Apple/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/CED4CA68-E9C8-4A23-9164-0CF1F25E15E9/sort_alg.app/news.plist
YeS2012-04-09 21:41:18.892 sort_alg[668:207] (
    4,
    2,
    5,
    8,
    1
)
2012-04-09 21:41:18.893 sort_alg[668:207] /Users/Apple/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/4.2/Applications/CED4CA68-E9C8-4A23-9164-0CF1F25E15E9/sort_alg.app/news.plist
array1 2 4

Comment: as u see the list has for example 5 numbers 4 2 5 8 1 and the NSlog trace shows the plist data and crashes when sorting

Comment: there is no hint of a crash in this log... I understand those are your NSLog statements, but there should be more info on the console... by the way, how are you sorting the array?

Comment: I suggest you to run the program step by step and look at which line the program crashes on.

Comment: when i use the following  //NSMutableArray *array = [[NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"1", @"9", @"7",@"3", @"5", nil]mutableCopy]; all work fine and the sort works fine but the crash happen when i replcae this line wit the  NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile: path];